# how to create multiple list with different set of values in a loop in python?

Tags: python

I'm struggle to create multiple lists with different sets of values. I try to read a csv using pandas and then for every 100 records I want to set it in a list, and then until it reach the bottom of the csv.
The csv file example:

```
number
1
2
...
100
```

here is my code so far

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',')

n = 10
m = 0

mylist = []

while n < 25:

    for i in range(m, n):
        test = df.iloc[i]['number']
        mylist.append(test)
    print(mylist)

    print('finish 10 records')

    m += 10
    n += 10

    if n >= 25:

        for i in range(m, n):
            test = df.iloc[i]['number']
            mylist.append(test)
        print(mylist)
        print('finished')
        break
```

as you can see the code create this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
finish 10 records
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
finish 10 records
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
finish 10 records
```

what I want to achieve is this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
finish 10 records
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
finish 10 records
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
finish 10 records
```

is that possible to achieve that please?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're appending those values to the existing `mylist` variable and printing it as-is. You need to make sure you clear that list upon every iteration so that it starts empty, like this:

```
...

mylist = []
while n < 25:
    for i in range(m, n):
        ...

    print(mylist)
    mylist = []

    ...
```

Or, you could create a new list every iteration:

```
while n < 25:
    l = []

    for i in range(m, n):
        ...
        l.append(...)

    print(l)
```